# $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] -Xampp Error

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>NewsLetter Registration Time! </h1>
<form action='$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]' method='post'>
Enter the username to be added:
<input type="text" id="nt1" name="username"/>
Enter the corresponding email-id to be added:
<input type="text" id="nt1" name="email_id"/>
<input type="submit"/>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "<h1 style='color:red;'> Entering Data..... </h1>";
    $database=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','userdetails')
or die("didn't work");

mysqli_query($database,"INSERT INTO userdetails (username,password)VALUES ($_POST[username],$_POST[email_id])");

mysqli_close($database);
echo "<h3 style='color:red;'> Check the database..... </h3>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to access Database using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` but the code works if I use some other php script in action. Is this a problem with xampp?

Error:[image]

Comment: You forgot your PHP tags

Comment: @JohnConde It doesn't work even after adding php tags!

Comment: `<form action='$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]' method='post'>` that's because you're not in PHP with it - just do `action=''`. and everything inside this `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` won't fire up.

Comment: then this will fail you also `($_POST[username],$_POST[email_id])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing php tag in your forms and `type=submit` in your submit button. Also, check the [manual](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) for inserting data in database using php

```
<html>
    <body>
    <h1>NewsLetter Registration Time! </h1>
    <form action='<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method='post'>
    Enter the username to be added:
    <input type="text" id="nt1" name="username"/>
    Enter the corresponding email-id to be added:
    <input type="text" id="nt1" name="email_id"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo "<h1 style='color:red;'> Entering Data..... </h1>";
        $database=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','userdetails')
    or die("didn't work");

    mysqli_query($database,"INSERT INTO userdetails (username,password)VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[email_id]')");

    mysqli_close($database);
    echo "<h3 style='color:red;'> Check the database..... </h3>";
    }
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Now I access to the database, but the values are not being entered into the table.

Comment: `name=submit` is missing//

Comment: Yes. I have one more doubt `"INSERT INTO userdetails (username,email_id) VALUES ('{$_POST['username']}','{$_POST['email_id']}')");` works but  this `"INSERT INTO userdetails (username,email_id) VALUES ('($_POST['username']','($_POST['email_id'])')"); ` doesn't. Only difference is the curly bracket.

Comment: You should check manual for that . I have attached a link in the answer . Also, pleas upvote/accept  the answer so that it will be helpful to others too.